# How to read specific lines that contain a specific string with Pandas read_csv()?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to sort out only the columns and rows I want to use when downloading a CSV.

with

```
df = pd.read_csv("https://data.org/data.csv",usecols = ['Lion','Tree'])
```

I can read only the columns I want, but how can I read only the rows whose column "Lion" contains the word "animal" for example?

Answer (score 1):

- If what you're asking for is to filter rows **while** reading the csv file, the answer is that there is no built-in way to do that.
- But you can do what you want when the csv file has been loaded in a DataFrame like that:

`df = df.loc[df['Lion'] == 'animal']`

**Explanation:**

`DataFrame.loc` allows you to access a group of rows and columns by label(s) or a boolean array.

And here, `df['Lion'] == 'animal'` will return a boolean array like for example:

```
0    True
3    True
```

This means that rows 0 and 3 match the condition where the values are equal to the string `'animal'`.

So, `loc` will select these rows 0 and 3.